# Modify Data that is put into CGridView - Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm working on a project in Yii where I would like the user to be able to update information on his mobile "accounts". The database I use has multiple accounts for each person (and, for that matter, has multiple individuals who will use the system). Now, when the user goes to "manage his account" he is able to manage *all* of the accounts of the database (not just his own).

Currently the code in the controller looks like this

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model =new Account('search');
    $userId = Login::model()->getUserId(); 
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Account']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Account'];
    }
    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

UserId is the the id that I would like to restrict that data to. Something along the lines of

```
$account = Account::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"user_id = $userId"));
```

I'm not sure how exactly to go through with this. I've looked around and I know that there are "Criteria" that I could update in the model and there is also a "Filter function in the view". Should I be using one of these two to limit the accounts shown? Or can I do something directly from the controller?

Here is the code in the view

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'account-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'user_id',
    'name',
    'mobile_comp',
    'msisdn',
    'pin',
    'balance',
    /*
    'company',
    */
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
```

)); ?>

And the model

```
    public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('mobile_comp',$this->mobile_comp,true);
    $criteria->compare('msisdn',$this->msisdn);
    $criteria->compare('pin',$this->pin);
    $criteria->compare('company',$this->company,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your actionAdmin to the following

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
   $model =new Account('search');
   $userId = Login::model()->getUserId(); 
   $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
   if(isset($_GET['Account']))
   {
      $model->attributes=$_GET['Account'];
   }
   $model->user_id = $userId;
   $this->render('admin',array(
      'model'=>$model,
   ));
 }
```

The above code will load only the current user record.

Comment: This didn't limit the models displayed it only put in the value of the UserId to be searched for.

Answer (score 0):

Just Solved - Different way than Think Different:

In my model I added a condition

```
    public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $userId = Login::model()->getUserId(); 
    $criteria->addCondition(array("condtion"=>"user_id = $userId"));
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('mobile_comp',$this->mobile_comp,true);
    $criteria->compare('msisdn',$this->msisdn);
    $criteria->compare('pin',$this->pin);
    $criteria->compare('company',$this->company,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```